# Geokit Rails distance and find(:all)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, geokit

I have 2 questions regarding the `gem 'geokit-rails'`

This is my sample code

```
class Outlet < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_mappable :lat_column_name => :address_latitude,
                   :lng_column_name => :address_longitude,
                   :default_units => :kms
end
```

1. I cant use the find(:all)

   sample `Outlet.find(:all, :origin =>[32.951613,-96.958444], :within=>10)`
   it returns 
   `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Outlets with 'id': (all, {:origin=>[32.951613, -96.958444], :within=>10})`

   I have also tested on this query `Outlet.find(:all)`
   it returns `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Outlet with 'id'=all`
2. Distance. I dont really understand how does this work. Should we add distance column into the the outlet model ? If yes, whats the column type? And is that possible to return the record with the distance value based on the given lat lng ? `Outlet.by_distance(:origin =>[32.951613, -96.958444])`
   it will return the records with the distance to that point. (2kms, 3kms, 4km, ...)

Answer (score 0):

1. [find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) is an ActiveRecord method. **It has nothing to do with Geokit**. It takes model `id` such as `1` for the first Outlet you created or `2` for the second Outlet. You used `Outlet.find(:all)` so, ActiveRecord complained that it could not find any Outlet with id `all`.

   **I think what you actually wanted to do is**

   ```
   Outlet.within(10, :origin => [32.951613,-96.958444])
   ```

   Note that you can also pass an object for origin, for example,

   ```
   @the_latest_outlet = Outlet.last
   @outlets_nearby_the_latest_outlet = Outlet.within(10, origin: @the_latest_outlet)
   ```
2. No, you don't have to add a column. The field `distance` is added to ActiveRecord instances automatically. I still haven't found any use of the parameter `:distance_field_name`. My best guess is that if your model has a field named `distance`, you should use `distance_field_name` parameter to avoid the conflict.

   *2.1.* If you want to measure distance between 2 points, you need [distance_to](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/geokit/geokit/master/Geokit/Mappable:distance_to) as this example:

   ```
   a = Outlet.find(1)
   b = Outlet.find(2)
   distance_from_a_to_b = a.distance_to(b)
   ```

   *2.2.* `by_distance` is to get all your instances sorted by distance.

   ```
   a_place_to_compare = [lat, lng]
   all_outlets_sorted_by_distance_from_the_place = Outlet.by_distance(a_place_to_compare)
   ```